# JQL for Epics that have stories in the current sprint?

Tags: jira, jql

Is there a way to get the list of epics that have issues in the current sprint? I'm aware of `sprint in openSprints()`, but that returns the issues themselves. Typically in our setup the epics don't belong to any one sprint.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works with

```
issueFunction in issuesinEpics("issueFunction in epicsOf(\"Sprint in openSprints()\")")
```

in case someone is still interested xD

Comment: I cannot find the `issuesinEpics` function. Is this from a plugin?

Answer (score -1):

If you have scriptrunner installed you can use the following code

```
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("Sprint in openSprints()", "has Epic")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
issueFunction in epicsOf("Sprint in openSprints()")
```